# jQuery Mootools not working - tried some tricks

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I'm issues getting JQuery to work with Mootools, and I've tried just about every thing I've found on resolving the conflict, so I'm thinking I'm just doing it wrong, and not realizing it.

Here's the code without the libraries listed:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.slideshow').cycle({
            fx: 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp,         shuffle, etc...
        });
    })(jQuery);


    <script type="text/javascript">

    (function($){
    window.addEvent('domready', function() {

      var status = {
        'true': 'HIDE',
        'false': ''
       };



      var myVerticalSlide = new Fx.Slide('vertical_slide').hide();



        $('v_toggle').addEvent('click', function(event){
        event.stop();
        myVerticalSlide.toggle();
        });



      myVerticalSlide.addEvent('complete', function() {
       $('vertical_status').set('text', status[myVerticalSlide.open]);
          });

            });
            })(document.id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery instead of $

```
jQuery('.slideShow')
```

$ is a reference to jQuery so they're interchangeable

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about mootools but they both use the $ identifider. I believe you need to reassign the $ to one of them.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

So now when you want to use jQuery you do

```
$j('selector').show();
```

And you use the same syntax as before for Mootools.

Comment: MooTools doesn't replace $ if it's already in use. Because his whole MooTools code is in a nice anonymous function, he can just skip jQuery.noConflict() if it's loaded before MooTools is.

Comment: yep - IF he's using a recent mootools and not 1.11, 1.12, 1.2, 1.2.1